# How to populate dynamic inputs from JSON array api returned in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have this line of code

```
  <div data-bind="foreach: arrayreturned">
  <input type="text"  data-bind="value: textValue, valueUpdate:'keyup'"  />
   </div>
```

I know how to bind array from knockout itself, but if i have json array returned from api , how can i bind using foreach directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `arrayreturned` an [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) before adding the results to it:

```
var arrayreturned = ko.observableArray(yourApiResults);
```

Comment: You mean if directly put my arrayobject returned by api, its automatically populate ?

Comment: Yes, from the link above `If you want your observable array not to start empty, but to contain some initial items, pass those items as an array to the constructor`

Comment: Actully , ,my problem is its my jsp page, and the array variable come from java in the jsp, that's why i cannot access it in my javascript file.  Could i access it ?

Comment: Then generate the javascript string for the array in JSP